# Material table : Sorting and displaying grouped data

Tags: sorting, grouped-table, mat-table

I have a datasource that has data which is grouped. For e.g.
parent:
- name- string
- segments- arrayList of segment objects(each segment object has title and description

I'm trying to use a mat-table to display data in rows and columns as follows :
[image]

I want to use mat-sort and sort within the segment groups when I click on segment header (ie after sorting segments, sorted data should look like this):
[image]

When I click on Name (header) the table should be sorted as follows:
[image]

How can I do the same? Is there a good way to group my rows in the above format. (Right now I'm using divs within mat cell to display the content which doesn't seem right).
I have tried using an approach for displaying similar to [this link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mattable-with-groupheader?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.html)
However when I add mat-sort to this group headers get sorted on top and the rows come below.

[This link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aejwfm-6htvuk?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.html)
 has example to display data the required way